# How to make datatable headers span a number of columns

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a simple JSF datatable, which currently has four columns, one header row and (with current data) three data rows.

I have to add three extra columns; that part's easy.
I also want to add another header row before the existing header row with headers that span a subset of the columns.

The desired result is something like:
Column 1: first row empty; header on second row.
Columns 2-4: first row header spans 3 columns; second row has individual column headers.
Columns 5-7: first row header spans 3 columns; second row has individual column headers.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Following are images showing what it should look like.

1. This is the data table before I've changed anything.
   [Table Example 1 http://www.isw.com.au/home/sjleis/stuff.nsf/tableexample1.gif](http://www.isw.com.au/home/sjleis/stuff.nsf/tableexample1.gif)
2. This is the data table after I've added three columns. I was able to do this easily.
   [Table Example 1 http://www.isw.com.au/home/sjleis/stuff.nsf/tableexample2.gif](http://www.isw.com.au/home/sjleis/stuff.nsf/tableexample2.gif)
3. This shows the desired end result, which I can't figure out. Note the "Retail Sales" and "Fleet/Gov Sales" headers each span three columns.
   [Table Example 1 http://www.isw.com.au/home/sjleis/stuff.nsf/tableexample3.gif](http://www.isw.com.au/home/sjleis/stuff.nsf/tableexample3.gif)

Comment: Can you add an image of a mock-up of what you mean. It's not clear to me.

Comment: did you manage to work your issue around? Share.

Comment: RichFaces seems to be difficult or impossible to enable on the platform (WebSphere Portal 6.0). For the specific application, I've decided to avoid the spanned headers and instead add words to clarify individual headers. The customer seems OK with my "too hard" explanation. As for marking an answer, I don't know what I should do here.

Answer (score 4):

This would be easy if you were using Richfaces (as Bozho mentions) with the `breakBefore` attribute.

Here's a quick example:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{countryCodeListFactory}" var="c">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column colspan="2">Main</rich:column>
            <rich:column colspan="4">Other Details</rich:column>
            <rich:column breakBefore="true">Country ID</rich:column>
            <rich:column>Name</rich:column>
            <rich:column>Region</rich:column>
            <rich:column>Alpha</rich:column>
            <rich:column>ISO</rich:column>
            <rich:column>Flag Path</rich:column>
        </rich:columnGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <rich:column>#{c.countryId}</rich:column>
    <rich:column>#{c.countryName}</rich:column>
    <rich:column>#{c.region}</rich:column>
    <rich:column>#{c.alpha3}</rich:column>
    <rich:column>#{c.isoNum}</rich:column>
    <rich:column>#{c.flagImage}</rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

If you're not then hopefully you're using facelets. Then you can build the table manually using the `<ui:repeat>`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Main</th>
        <th colspan="4">Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Region</th>
        <th>Alpha</th>
        <th>ISO</th>
        <th>Flag</th>
    </tr>
    <ui:repeat value="#{countryCodeListFactory}" var="c">
    <tr>
        <td>#{c.countryId}</td>
        <td>#{c.countryName}</td>
        <td>#{c.region}</td>
        <td>#{c.alpha3}</td>
        <td>#{c.isoNum}</td>
        <td>#{c.flagImage}</td>
    </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a very good answer (very useful to me, thanks!). You should accept it.

Comment: Does not work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688009/jsf-richtable-merging-rows-in-a-header  (even though I use richFaces)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `<h:dataTable>`. Well, you can with some ugly hacks, like modifying the DOM with javascript and adding the desired columns, but that's not what you should do.

Take a look at [RichFaces dataTable](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?c=dataTable&tab=usage) - its columns support the `colspan` attribute.

Comment: Yours and Damo's answers both seem to cover it, but I'm not marking an answer until I determine if I can get RichFaces working on Websphere Portal 6.0. I hadn't considered the server software relevant since I thought the h:dataTable was all I had to work with.