# JSF RichTable merging rows / columns in a header

Tags: jsf, richfaces

What I want to do is do this layout with `RichTable` in its header to have 3 columns:

```
+---+---+-------+
|   |   | 3   5 |
| 1 | 2 |-------+
|   |   | 4   6 |
+---+---+-------+
```

I got used [this](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.0.X/4.0.0.Alpha2/en-US/Component_Reference/html/chap-Component_Reference-Tables_and_grids.html) (8.2) resource to get it done. **Rich-faces 4.0.0**

But instead I end up having plain table-row with no any merging.

Could you please shed a light on this?

**Update:**

About the answer from **Vasil Lukach**. In my case (if I do copy paste of those code), I have this result (I use hard coded values to keep it simple):

[image: as we can see.. it is a mess]

My code looks like this:

```
 <rich:dataTable id="mydatatable"
                                    value="#{applicationListBean.data}" >

                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="msg.txnLineItems" />
                        <rich:columnGroup>
                            <rich:column rowspan="2">
                                <h:outputText value="msg.item" />
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column rowspan="2">
                                <h:outputText value="msg.department" />
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column rowspan="2">
                                <h:outputText value="msg.purchaseAmount}" />
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column rowspan="2">
                                <h:outputText value="msg.quantity" />
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column colspan="5">
                                <h:outputText value="msg.promotions" />
                            </rich:column>

                            <rich:column breakRowBefore="true">
                                <h:outputText value="msg.promoName" />
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="msg.promoCode" />
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="msg.promoCategory" />
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="msg.discount" />
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="msg.points" />
                            </rich:column>
                        </rich:columnGroup>
                    </f:facet>

                </rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `<rich:column rowspan="2">` and `<rich:column breakRowBefore="true">` for similar table: 
[image: Result]

Code

```
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.txnLineItems}" />
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column rowspan="2">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.item}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column rowspan="2">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.department}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column rowspan="2">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.purchaseAmount}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column rowspan="2">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.quantity}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column colspan="5">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.promotions}" />
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column breakRowBefore="true">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.promoName}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.promoCode}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.promoCategory}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.discount}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.points}" />
            </rich:column>
        </rich:columnGroup>
        </f:facet>
```

Comment: Yeah. Like I said, I've already seen similar solutions here and there, and those supposed to work, but I wonder why my doesn't.

Comment: Maybe your problem is related to table width. Try add `style` attribute in `rich:dataTable` and set width, for example `style="width: 100%"`.