# Merge Rows Dynamically at RichFaces Table Center

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 4, and I need merge two rows in table center, such as:

```
+---+---+-------+
|   |   |   |   |
|---|   |-------+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+-------+
```

I tried using the following code:

```
        <rich:column >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="col 1" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="val 1" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column breakRowBefore="true">
            <h:outputText value="Val 2" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column rowspan="2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Col 2" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="Val 2" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Col 3" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="Val 3" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column breakRowBefore="true">
            <h:outputText value="Val 4" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Col 4" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="Val 5" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column breakRowBefore="true">
            <h:outputText value="Val 6" />
        </rich:column>
```

But using this way the third column breaks. If I do merge in columns at the end of the table, like this [JSF RichTable merging rows / columns in a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688009/jsf-richtable-merging-rows-columns-in-a-header) , It will work fine. But this don't solve my problem.

Comment: "the third column breaks" doesn't explain what your problem is. Your code shows only 4 cells, while the "drawing" has 7. Bear in mind the numbering is by rows (i.e. the first row will be 1-2-3-4, not 1-3-4-5)

Comment: I edited the table for a better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it more difficult than it needs to be, it works pretty much like the standard HTML. `breakRowBefore` simply starts a new row (and so all following columns will be on the same row or lower). Your example has two rows so you have to use it only once:

```
<column>
<column rowspan="2">
<column>
<column>

<column breakRowBefore="true">
<column>
<column>
```